# Doxygen: warning end of file while inside a group

Tags: python, doxygen

As the title says Doxygen doesn't seem to notice my closing "}" of the group. This is what my Python file looks like:

```
##
#   @defgroup api_ironpy IronPython
#   @brief IronPython API
#
#   @defgroup api_ironpy_foo Foo
#   @ingroup api_ironpy
#   @{
#

My Foo class definition goes here...

##
#   @}
#
```

Even if I remove my class definition and just create the group I get the same warning, so my class is not interfering. Any idea what is causing this and how it can be fixed? I am using the default settings created by Doxywizard and this is the only source file in my Doxygen project.

I have used the same procedure when creating groups in another project (C++/C# instead of Python) without problems, in those files it looks like this:

```
///
/// @defgroup api_c_cpp C/C++
/// @brief C/C++ API
///
/// @defgroup api_c_cpp_bar Bar
/// @ingroup api_c_cpp
/// @{
///

Code goes here...

///
/// @}
///
```

Comment: Using Doxygen 1.8.9.1, your sample file works without errors or warnings on my system.

Comment: That's interesting, I use the same version of Doxygen and I get the warning. You did try the first piece of code right and not the second?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the following with doxygen version `1.8.13` and `1.8.11`.

When I close the group as following, it works. Please notice the extra new line after `## @}` and before final `#`.

```
## @} 

#
```

I do not know why this works, but it works.

I have tested with [this example (pythonSample.py/cfg)](https://github.com/yosoufe/doxygen/tree/yousof/grouping_diff_py_vs_cpp/examples/groupingDiffs).

Comment: Note that the current doxygen version is 1.8.18